# JWplayer raising Could not load plugins: File not found Error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, jwplayer

I saw many answers for **Could not load plugins:File not found**. but it's bit different.

I am using jwplayer for my rails app and i am playing videos in bootstrap modal.

After page load if i click video to play in bootstrap it is raising above error after closing that modal and again i clicked the same video it is playing video now(My page not refreshed).

I tried again after refreshing my page but for first time again same problem.

Tried with two browsers same issue.

```
$('.playuservideo').click(function() {
   var videopath=$(this).data('videopath');
   jwplayer('myElement').setup({'flashplayer': "/assets/flash.swf", 'id': 'playerID', 'width': '540','height': '360', 'file': videopath });
         $('#playallmodal').modal('show');      
});
```

Comment: Please provide a link :-)

Comment: i am testing on my local server

Comment: You need to put something up if you are seeking support. We can't guess.

Comment: hi thanks for your reply,   I added thin server to my gem file,it resolved the issue may be processing with webrick is issue

Comment: Glad you got it solved! :-)